# Angular ng-repeat to print array values in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an array in my app.js file, contents of which I would like to print sequentially in `<td>` rows in my HTML table.
Below is my app.js file:

```js
(function () {
 var app = angular.module('TravelI', []);

var route = [{
    source : [
        "San Jose",
        "San Francisco",
    ],

    destination : [
        "Wellington",
        "Mumbai"
    ],


}];
app.controller('RouteController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.product = route;

    $scope.addRoute = function(s, d) {

    };

});

})();
```

HTML code:

```html
<div id="DisplayTable" ng-repeat="x in product">
        <table style="width: 80%" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    From
                </th>
                <th>
                    To
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{x.source[$index]}}</td>
                <td>{{x.destination[$index]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Now I can only see the data correctly for the first element in the arrays. I want the display to be like this:

```
From                         To:
San Jose                     Wellington
San Francisco                Mumbai
```

Any city that I append to the two arrays should be displayed sequentially in the table rows.

Currently I can only see the first element in both the arrays:
[image]

Comment: It is printing only one row because your product.length is 1. you have to loop through product.source.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to reformat the $scope.product to be a key value pair, otherwise you can do this,assuming its always going to be two values,

```
  <table style="width: 80%" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    From
                </th>
                <th>
                    To
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{x.source[$index]}}</td>
                <td>{{x.destination[$index]}}</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{x.source[$index+1]}}</td>
                <td>{{x.destination[$index+1]}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

**EDIT:**

```
 <div id="DisplayTable" ng-repeat="x in product">
    <table style="width: 80%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>
          From
        </th>
        <th>
          To
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="y in x.source">{{y}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="y in x.destination">{{y}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/NegOfnC53PAFxPqHq5yd?p=preview)**

Comment: Would it be possible to increment the value in the HTML page with a variable so that every time a new element is added to the array, it would also be reflected in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If `route.source.length === route.destination.length` in your route, you can try this.

```js
    (function () {
        var app = angular.module('TravelI', []);

        var route = [{
            source : [
                "San Jose",
                "San Francisco",
                "src A",
                "src B"
            ],

            destination : [
                "Wellington",
                "Mumbai",
                "des A",
                "des B"
            ]
        }];
        app.controller('RouteController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.product = route;

            $scope.addRoute = function(s, d) {

            };

        });

    })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="TravelI">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Snippet</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="DisplayTable" ng-controller="RouteController">
    <table style="width: 80%" align="center" ng-repeat="x in product">
        <tr>
            <th>
                From
            </th>
            <th>
                To
            </th>
        </tr>
        <!-- I saw $scope.addRoute() has two arguments -->
        <!-- so, I assumed that source.length === destination.length -->
        <tr ng-repeat="src in x.source track by $index">
            <td>{{x.source[$index]}}</td>
            <td>{{x.destination[$index]}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```